# Bulk-Insert Select performance over individual Inserts

Tags: mysql, performance, bulk-insert

I am using [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) as ORM for my `nodejs` application.

**The scenario is**, I have to insert a `Poll` and its `Options` and get their objects.

**Approach 1:**

1 - Insert `Poll`:

```
INSERT INTO `polls` (`id`,`start_at`,`expire_at`,`options_count`) VALUES (DEFAULT,1487945658,1487945965,3);
```

2 - Insert `Options` *(bulk insert)*:

```
INSERT INTO `poll_options` (`id`,`poll_id`,`text`) VALUES (NULL,{id},'red'),(NULL,{id},'green'),(NULL,{id},'blue');
```

3 - Select `Options` *(I have to select because I don't get `id` of inserted `Option` due to bulk insertion)*:

```
SELECT `id`, `poll_id`, `text` FROM `poll_options` WHERE `poll_id` = {id};
```

**Approach 2:**

1 - Insert `Poll`

2 - Insert each `Option` one by one *(this way I can get inserted `id` as well, so no need of explicit SELECT at the end)*

**Question:**

Which `approach` would be better?

Both tables have referential integrity enabled and using innodb engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking **performance**, first approach is better. **Here is why:**

Whenever new data is inserted into a table, the indexes will also be updated, and physically reordered. In the case on InnoDB, not only are the index files updated, but the data file itself could be reordered, it is *clustered* based on the primary key. So, re-ordering/updating is an expensive operation, and you want to minimize it.

When you do bulk insert, the indexes are updated at when the statement is finished. i.e. after inserting all rows.
On the other hand, when you do individual inserting, physical files are updated after each insert.

The overhead of the last `select` statement in the first approach is negligible.

Comment: **Talking about approach 2**, if I use `transaction`. Will it make a difference? Because physical indexes will not be touched until `commit`.

Comment: I think yes, it makes difference. However, you are still hitting the disk more often than in approach one. Because even transactions are stored on disk (In 'ib_logfile's). In other words, approach 2 with transactions is better than not using transaction, but still worse than approach 1. I'd like to see others' input about this point.

Comment: I get it, thanks a lot for detailed answer.

Comment: Any decent RDBMS will offload the house keeping operations to background processes. You also do not discuss caching of blocks in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Although you're using an ORM, which hides the nitty gritty details of SQL for your developers, you seem to be interested in different approaches to insert a record and a multitude of detail records in a child table.

I would opt for the code, which conveys the intend most clearly and which can be maintained more easily. In my opinion, this will likely be the second option. Only if (measured) performance is an issue, then I would start optimizing.

Comment: Yeah I also prefer that, but it will not be too complicated and can be explained by comments, but performance boost I get here will be much much valuable.

Answer (score 0):

But those are not the same??  Approach 1 retrieves one of the 3 ids; Approach 2 retrieves each of 3 ids.

And, why do you need any `id` from `poll_options`?

Seems like this is all you need:

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO `polls` (`start_at`,`expire_at`,`options_count`)
    VALUES (1487945658,1487945965,3);
-- note: no mention of polls.id, above.

{id} = LAST_INSERT_ID() -- however your language does this

INSERT INTO `poll_options` (`poll_id`,`text`)
     VALUES
     ({id},'red'),
     ({id},'green'),
     ({id},'blue');
-- again, no mention of poll_options.id

COMMIT;
```

Even so, the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` are not really required.  (At worst, you could might store a row in `polls`, then fail to store the rows in `poll_options`.

Performance:

- 1+1 inserts is nearly twice as fast as 1+3 inserts
- Getting `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is faster than any `SELECT`.

Comment: **(1)** Both approaches are same, I am not `SELECT`ing one `poll_option` I am actually getting all three by their parent id *(which is `poll_id`)*. **(2)**  I need to get all inserted ids for `poll_options`, how can I get them if I perform `bulk insert`? That is the main problem, I had to go for explicit SELECT to get `ids`.

Comment: What will you then do with the 3 ids?

Comment: Create the objects and respond to request, its an API

Comment: Then it is sort of a tossup.  Consider each `INSERT` and each `SELECT` ad "1 unit of effort"; exclude the fetching of a single `LAST_INSERT_ID`.  From that, you can judge which Approach is slightly faster.  The bottom line is: it won't matter a lot unless you have lots of rows.